# C++: incorrect swapping of nodes in linked list

Tags: c++, pointers

I have 2 simple structures:

```
struct Address
{
    char city[255];
};
typedef Address* AddressPtr;

struct Person
{
    char fullName[255];
    Address* address;
    Person* next;
};
typedef Person* PersonPtr;
```

The Person structure forms the Linked list where new elements are added to the beginning of the list. What I want to do is to sort them by `fullName`. At first I tried to swap links, but I lost the beginning of the list and as a result my list was sorted partially. Then I decided to sort list by swapping the values of nodes. But I get strange results. For a list with names: `Test3, Test2, Test1`, I get `Test3, Test3, Test3`.

Here is my sorting code:

```
void sortByName(PersonPtr& head)
{
    TaskPtr currentNode, nextNode;
    for(currentNode = head; currentNode->next != NULL; currentNode = currentNode->next)
    {
        for(nextNode = currentNode->next; nextNode != NULL; nextNode = nextNode->next)
        {
            if(strcmp(currentNode->fullName, nextNode->fullName) > 0)
            {
                swapNodes(currentNode, nextNode);
            }
        }

    }
}

void swapNodes(PersonPtr& node1, PersonPtr& node2)
{
    PersonPtr temp_node = node2;
    strcpy(node2->fullName, node1->fullName);
    strcpy(node1->fullName, temp_node->fullName);

    strcpy(node2->address->city, node1->address->city);
    strcpy(node1->address->city, temp_node->address->city);
}
```

After the sorting completion, nodes values are a little bit strange.

**UPDATED**

This is how I swapped links:

```
void swapNodes(PersonPtr& node1, PersonPtr& node2)
{
    PersonPtr temp_person;
    AddressPtr temp_address;

    temp_person = node2;
    node2 = node1;
    node1 = temp_person;

    temp_address = node2->address;
    node2->address = node1->address;
    node1->address = temp_address;
}
```

Comment: I think one of advantages of linked-lists is swapping nodes doesn't need swapping data and you just need to swap links.

Comment: Maybe I did it in a incorrect way, but I could simply get something like `Test1, Test3, Test2`.

Comment: I agree. Can you post the link-swapping code that doesn't work?

Comment: @godel9, Yes, sure, one moment please.

Comment: @MM.: I was just about to say the same thing.  That is about the only advantage of linked lists over arrays.

Comment: @MM., godel9, see my update.

Comment: As a suggestion, try using `std::string` instead of `char []`, and you don't need to do `typedef` for pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use strcpy.  When you swap nodes, you can accomplish that by swapping the .next member variable.  The only reason to use linked lists is to copy a bunch of data around.

In times like these, it's a good idea to draw out the situation on paper.  Draw several boxes in a line:

```
 W["1"] -> X["3"] -> Y["2"] -> Z["4"]
```

Ok, so, we have four nodes, W X Y and Z, set up so that W points to X, X points to Y, and Y points to Z.

Each node has a string value.  W's value is 1, X's value is 3, Y's value is 2, and Z's value is 4.

We want to sort the nodes so that the string values go in ascending order:  1, 2, 3, 4.

Now, you've been trying to accomplish that by swapping the actual data values around:

```
swap(X.data, Y.data)
```

... resulting in:

```
W["1"] -> X["2"] -> Y["3"] -> Z["4"]
```

That would work, but it's not a good idea, for many reasons.  It's very bug-prone, for one.  For two, you give up the main benefit of using linked lists:  swapping around the links, rather than the data.

Here's what it would look like if you swap the node linkages around:

```
 W["1"] -> Y["2"] -> X["3"] -> Z["4"]
```

Notice how none of the data moved -- W's value is still 1, X's value is still 3, Y's value is still 2, and Z's value is still 4.  But we've rearranged the traversal order:  now W leads to Y, which leads to X, which leads to Z, giving the expected result of 1, 2, 3, 4.

This may sound confusing, but it's simple once you get into the right mindset.  Let's break down the steps one at a time.

What's the difference between our initial state...

```
 W["1"] -> X["3"] -> Y["2"] -> Z["4"]
```

... and our desired state?

```
 W["1"] -> Y["2"] -> X["3"] -> Z["4"]
```

Aha, the difference is that we've swapped the middle two nodes.  So that's the operation we need to figure out how to do:  How do you swap two adjacent nodes?

Well, let's look at it like this.  W used to lead to X, which lead to Y, which lead to Z.

We want W to lead to Y;  we want Y to lead to X;  we want X to lead to Z.

Do you see?  That involves modifying three nodes.  You can't do it if you only know about two of the nodes.  You have to be able to modify three in a row.

Let's get rid of some clutter:

```
A -> B -> C -> D
```

We want to swap B and C, so that it winds up looking like:

```
A -> C -> B -> D
```

How?

Well, that graph is equivalent to the following:

```
A -> A.next -> A.next.next -> A.next.next.next
```

So here's what we can do.  Let's define an operation that takes a node, and swaps the two nodes after it.  So if we use our operation on A, then it will swap B and C around.  Or if we use our operation on B, then it will swap C and D around.

Here's how.

```
void swapAfter( Node* node ) {
  Node* A = node;
  Node* B = node->next;
  Node* C = node->next->next;
  Node* D = node->next->next->next;

  A->next = C; // Lead A to C
  C->next = B; // Lead C to B
  B->next = D; // Lead b to D

  // Now we have A->C->B->D!
}
```

And there we go.  Now we have a way of swapping around any two nodes.

The reason I decided to explain it this (roundabout) way is to help you understand and visualize what's going on with linked lists.  Beginners often have trouble mentally following what happens during the operations.  Usually they'll just blindly do what a book tells them to do and not really grok why it works.  Whereas with this example, each step is very obvious.

But that "swapAfter" function might not be very useful to you if you try to use it directly.  For one thing, it'll crash if you try to use it on the last node, because it has no error checking.  But the point was to give you an understanding of how linked lists work rather than give you a swapNodes function. :-)

The main takeaway is that you're not providing enough parameters to your swapNodes function... if you want to swap "curNode" and "nextNode", then at that point you must know which node comes before curNode ("prevNode").  Then you'd do something like:

```
Node* finalNode = nextNode->next;

// right now, we have..
//   prevNode -> curNode -> nextNode -> finalNode

// we want..
//   prevNode -> nextNode -> curNode -> finalNode

// so..
prevNode->next = nextNode;
nextNode->next = curNode;
curNode->next = finalNode;
```

Note that you'll have to do error checking in order to get this to work completely... e.g. what if nextNode is NULL?  Or what if prevNode is NULL (meaning curNode is the first node?)  Just work through each case one by one.

If you want to sidestep all of this complexity, there's really no reason to use linked lists.  Instead, you can make an array of pointers:

```
Person** people = new Person*[4];
for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  people[i] = new Person();
```

and then you can sort that array by just swapping around its elements:

```
if ( strcmp(people[1]->fullName, people[2]->fullName) > 0 )
  swap( people[1], people[2] );
```

No more dealing with 'next' pointers.  But now if you want to add more than 4 people to your array, you'll have to reallocate it, since it's a fixed size.  So that's the tradeoff.

Anyway, I hope this was somewhat helpful.  This is my first real Stack Overflow comment, so I apologize if it's a little rough.

Comment: I don't think your answer is rough, it is on the contrary great. I mean, you're right about "mental following on what happens in the background". I tried to operate with pointers and visualize their target like memory cells (they are memory cells indeed), but I had some trouble with full understanding on what is going on in the "real" background. Now I feel my mind was defragmented and I have more understanding in how swapping the links should work. I need to try achieve my goal with "renewed mind set". Hope you won't mind questions, if any.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped!  And of course, please feel free to ask me anything.  If you want some help outside of stackoverflow, you can reach me via email.  My address is sillysaurus2 at gmail.

Answer (score 1):

In order to swap nodes in a singly-linked list, you need more than just the two nodes you're swapping.  There are at least *three* pointers to modify.

```
+--------+ next +---------+ next +---------+ next +---------+
| before |----->|  node1  |----->|  node2  |----->|  after  |
+--------+      +---------+      +---------+      +---------+
```

To swap `node1` and `node2`, you need to swap `node1->next` and `node2->next`, and then point `before->next` at `node2`.  Of course, in order to modify `before->next`, you need to know `before`.  (And if the nodes aren't adjacent, you'd have to update `node2`'s parent as well.)

Now, if you're just swapping the data rather than the pointers, you'd be OK with just the two nodes you're swapping.  But you're doing two things horribly wrong, if that's the goal.

1. `temp_node` == `node2`. That means they're both *pointing at the same object*.  So when you copy data from `*node1` into `*node2`, you're modifying the same object `temp_node` points to.  Then when you copy from `*temp_node` into `*node1`, you're actually copying that data you've just overwritten.  End result: all nodes' address objects contain the same bits.

   You need `temp_node` to point to an independent object, or simply let it be a node object rather than a pointer, or copy the data into a buffer or something.
2. Swapping the pointers and swapping the data are mutually exclusive if you want to get something done.  Here, you swap the node pointers, and then you swap data pointers...?  Kinda defeats the purpose, doesn't it?

   Watch:

   ```
       //    node1             node2
       //    +----------+ next +----------+
       //    |   node   |----->|   node   |
       //    +----------+      +----------+
       //          | address        | address
       //          v                v
       //    +----------+      +----------+
       //    | address1 |      | address2 |
       //    +----------+      +----------+

       temp_person = node2;
       node2 = node1;
       node1 = temp_person;

       //    node2             node1
       //    +----------+ next +----------+
       //    |   node   |----->|   node   |
       //    +----------+      +----------+
       //          | address        | address
       //          v                v
       //    +----------+      +----------+
       //    | address1 |      | address2 |
       //    +----------+      +----------+
   ```

   So far, so good.  The two pointers are swapped.
   And that means `node1->address` sees the second node's address.

   But wait: Then you swap address pointers.

   ```
       temp_address = node2->address;
       node2->address = node1->address;
       node1->address = temp_address;

       //    node2             node1
       //    +----------+ next +----------+
       //    |   node   |----->|   node   |
       //    +----------+--+   +----------+
       //           address|        | address
       //          +-------|--------+
       //          v       |
       //    +----------+  |   +----------+
       //    | address1 |  +-->| address2 |
       //    +----------+      +----------+
   ```

   So now, `node1->address` points at `address1`.  You have *unswapped* the data.

   So decide whether you want to swap pointers or data.  If you swap the data, you only need the two nodes' pointers, and don't modify the `next` pointers.  If you're swapping whole nodes, on the other hand, you need the "before" node, and you don't touch the data pointers -- the whole point of swapping the pointers is to rearrange the data.

Comment: Hm. I need `head` pointer that will be always up-to-date. Or modify my linked list to be `two-way linked list`. Then I could easily find the head node by `prev` pointer to be `NULL`. Isn't it too complicated for sorting?

Comment: Probably.  Linked lists often suck for sorting in the first place; most sort algorithms effectively require random access.  Bubble sort is one of the few viable ones, as it always works with adjacent elements.

Comment: What you could do is return the pointer to `node2`, and consider it replacing `node1`.  Watch:  `NodePtr swapWithNext(NodePtr n1) { NodePtr n2 = n1->next; std::swap(n1->next, n2->next); return n2; }`.  Then use it like `before->next = swapWithNext(before->next);`.  Or, for the head... `head = swapWithNext(head);`.

Comment: You could pass `n1` by reference if you wanted, and have the function update the pointer itself.  But that kinda creeps me out; it's a bit too easy to pass a copy of a pointer rather than a reference to one, and in that case, the original pointer wouldn't be updated.  Something like that should definitely not be part of the public API; it's too error prone for users to muck around with.  I'd only trust it if it were a private member function of a class, and were insanely well documented even then.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using single linked list to swap two elements you should run it from the beginning till the last element to swap. While running it is necessary to find two previous pointers to these two elements which have to be swapped (one previous pointer may be null if element is the first in the list). Then this loop finished (at the seconds element to swap) you must have four: first element to swap (first), previous to first element (first_prev; may be null), second element (second) and the previous element to swap (second_prev; may be null). Then you need just to swap them in way like this:

```
  temp_first_next = first->next;
  temp_second_next = second->next;

  /* put first element at place of the second */
  first->next = temp_second_next;
  if (second_prev) {
    second_prev->next = first;
  }

  /* put second element at place of the first */
  second->next = temp_first_next;
  if (first_prev) {
    first_prev->next = next;
  }
```

And if you are really using C++ it is better to switch to using [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), [std::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) and use classes for each element. It will be easier, less pointers. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises from the fact that you are swapping the elements of the list while iterating through it.

Another approach could be to run through the list and swap objects until it runs through the list once without swapping any elements.

Comment: Won't it affect the performance? But what am I talking about...bubble sort is already ineffective sorting algorithm.